# get data-value with variable value

Tags: javascript, php

I have a `data-value` in my php code that is used in several places, for example:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" data-value="<?= $i ?>"></a>
<a class="dropdown-item" data-value="<?= $k ?>"></a>
```

And now I need to use one of these values ​​in the script

```
getAttribute('data-value')
```

But I can’t just use `data-value`, since it will be relevant to everything that I have, I only need to use this `data-value="<?= $k ?>"`

How can I specify a value with this variable in the script?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding here it should not be part of a `class` instead do `<a class="dropdown-item" data-value="<?= $i ?>"></a>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is not part of the class, I just made a little mistake, I changed it as it should be, sorry

Comment: if you have more than one `data-value` on different html elements, first you have to identify the specific html element and then you access the data value. so like `elem.getAttribute('data-value');`

Comment: @RiggsFolly But when I even have the same class names, how can I define it? add a separate class for this?

Comment: yes, or an `id`

Comment: We woudl need to see more of your actual code to know how to give a more specific answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly My actual code is the same, the classes are the same everywhere, only the variables are different, it seems that the only way out is to add a new class for this

Comment: Show the specific code where you need to gain access to this `data-value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you want to get the data-value of a specific element with the $k variable, your best bet is giving an id to that specific element and selecting it by id:

HTML

```
<a id="element_with_k" class="dropdown-item" data-value="<?= $k ?>"></a>
```

JS

```
const elementWithK = document.getElementById('element_with_k');

elementWithK.dataset.value // "the content of $k"
```

In case thete are multiple elements that you want to select then you add an extra class to those elements, query all the elements that have the extra class , loop through them and get each element's value.

Hope this helps, cheers!